# Spyder 4/5 and python38.dll

Tags: python, spyder

My work computer suddenly got forced-upgraded from Spyder 4 to Spyder 5, and Python 3.8 to Python 3.9. Now I get the following error. I know this might mean it can't find the python38.dll file. I know the location of this file on my computer. How do I set the path to point to python38.dll?

Thank you for your help.

```
Unhandled Exception: System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> System.DllNotFoundException: Unable to load DLL 'python38': The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)
   at Python.Runtime.Runtime.Py_IsInitialized()
   at Python.Runtime.Runtime.Initialize(Boolean initSigs)
   at Python.Runtime.PythonEngine.Initialize(IEnumerable`1 args, Boolean setSysArgv, Boolean initSigs)
   at Python.Runtime.PythonEngine.InitExt()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.UnsafeInvokeInternal(Object obj, Object[] parameters, Object[] arguments)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
   at System.RuntimeType.InvokeMember(String name, BindingFlags bindingFlags, Binder binder, Object target, Object[] providedArgs, ParameterModifier[] modifiers, CultureInfo culture, String[] namedParams)
   at clrModule.PyInit_clr()
```

Comment: Do you have the option of running the standalone Spyder installer yourself? It has an option to install to your user only, which should not require admin privileges. In my experience it's easier to re-install Spyder than to attempt to troubleshoot it.

Comment: This is a .NET/CLR traceback, not a python one, so maybe you should clarify what exactly produces this output.

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy any code produces this error

Comment: Then why do you get a .NET stack trace? It makes no sense.

Comment: @SaaruLindestøkke my company blocks stand-alone installs, even for user-specific installs. I’ll get IT involved tmr…

Comment: Perhaps you can look into a portable version of Spyder: https://www.portabledevapps.net/python-portable.php